# Can't set req.url to directory serve-static nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm using serve-static, and it works perfectly with, for example, the string '/var/www/html'.

But, when I write

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
 var serve = serve-static(req.url, ...)
 serve(...)}
```

with the url:

> localhost/var/www/html

It returns me :

> 'can't get /var/www/html'

How can I redirect my request to the root of my serve-static site?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured out, that, if I want to put the directory in my url,
I just need to set serve-static('/', ...) 
and it will automatically add the url directory

Answer (score 0):

you have to concat the root path, which is in the var `__dirname`

```
 var serve = serve-static(__dirname + req.url, ...)
```